# Creating a column whose values depend on other columns and the created columns previous values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with the three columns names A, B, C and want to add a fourth column with the following condition:

Note: prev X = previous entry of the column X

```
D = IF(A < prev D) and (B > prev D)

THEN A

ELSE prev D
```

Is there a way other than using for loop for accomplishing this using pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = np.where((df['A'] < df['D'].shift(1)) & 
                   (df['B'] > df['D'].shift(1)), df['A'], df['D'].shift(1))
```

Obviously this will make the first row always return the value of `NaN` instead of `A` or `D` previous value since the first value in `df['D'].shift(1)` will be `NaN`